# Flask security incredibly slowing all https traffic

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-security

I am using Flask Security for creating a secure API.
I recently discovered that using @auth_token_required makes **each** one of my calls to the back end take approximately **50 times** longer. Https call time is increased from 100ms per request to 5+ seconds.
Replacing @auth_token_required with @login_required fixes the issue.

I found this thread on Github: [Slow token authentication](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/731) that describes the problem and frustration around this issue.

It seems that this is a part of intentional security throttling but it seems crazy to me to slow every request by a factor of 50. Do I need to move away from Flask Security and implement OAuth or does anyone in the community have an easy fix to this issue?

Please comment if you've encountered this issue and what you decided to do.

Answer (score 3):

I have played around with flask-security a bit trying to make it work for me in various scenarios. I have not needed to speed up hash so I may not have a straight answer so I may only point you in the right direction.

**EDIT** The official flask security in github is [this](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security). The links I used below point my fork which has several alterations so if you need to fork, fork the official one

1) Flask-Security uses passlib for hashing

2) As noted in the link you have shared, Flask-Security uses bcrypt which is intentionally slow

3) Bcrypt uses work factor to determine how long you would like it to take to hash data. In passlib, the work factor is represented by int variable called rounds

4 To hash data, flask security uses below function in [flask-security/utils.py](https://github.com/mnjenga/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/utils.py)

```
def hash_data(data):
    return _hashing_context.hash(encode_string(data))
```

5 to verify your hashed data (eg a token) it uses this function in the same file

```
def verify_hash(hashed_data, compare_data):
    return _hashing_context.verify(encode_string(compare_data), hashed_data)
```

6) The hashing_context is derived from passlib in [flask-security/core.py](https://github.com/mnjenga/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/core.py) like this in various places in the file

```
from passlib.context import CryptContext

def _get_hashing_context(app):
    schemes = cv('HASHING_SCHEMES', app=app)
    deprecated = cv('DEPRECATED_HASHING_SCHEMES', app=app)
    return CryptContext(
        schemes=schemes,
        deprecated=deprecated)

hashing_context=_get_hashing_context(app),
```

and finally in utils.py(earlier shared like this)

```
_hashing_context = LocalProxy(lambda: _security.hashing_context)
```

The CryptContext imported from passlib and used in six above can take another argument which is rounds a figure between 4 and 31, by default, it is 12 and as per the [docs](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html) increasing the round by one **DOUBLES** the amount of time it takes

Since CryptContext has no round value passed to it in flask security, i assume it uses the default of 12 so you can experiment with various figures to see how it goes. Something like

```
def _get_hashing_context(app):
        schemes = cv('HASHING_SCHEMES', app=app)
        deprecated = cv('DEPRECATED_HASHING_SCHEMES', app=app)
        return CryptContext(
            schemes=schemes,
            deprecated=deprecated,
            pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=your_rounds) #I added this line
```

So you will need to fork security, change your rounds to a figure that works for you and install your repo like this

```
pip install git+https://github.com/your_repo/flask-security
```

Thats quite a mouthful of info, I hope it will be somehow useful.
Let me know how it goes as I may need this in the not far future

Comment: Thank you Moses,  that is definitely a step towards the promised land. I was hoping for something out of the box which I am missing, or a quick fix. I think forking the security repo could be problematic in the future when updates and changes are available. In this case I would probably prefer to go towards OAuth2 but still exploring options.

Comment: @TacoEater I will try and make a feature request for future releases, that and allowing api registration and login (without CSRF tokens) which I have also had to implement in a fork. I hope those can be available in future releases